# All possible Permutation of a list of function

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

First, I only understand pseudo code.

I've got a list of functions. 
I'm trying to apply all the permutation possible to the list. Then, for every permutation, apply the first element in pos 1, then the one in pos 2, till the end. And repeat for every permutation.

As for example :

```
mylist = [ sum(1+1) , sum(2+2) , sum(3+3) ]

#This should outputs

[2 , 4 , 6]
[4 , 6 , 2]
[6 , 2 , 4]
[2 , 6 , 4]
[6 , 4 , 2]
[4 , 2 , 6]
```

The real problem is , I know it is easy to set up in C,Python,Java once you have the library for it, but I'm only able to use, and understand the pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

Getting all permutations from a list can be done in various ways, one of them is recursion.

You have asked for pseudo code:

```
findPermutations (list,i):
   if i == list.length:
        foo(list)
        return
   for each j from i to list.length:
        swap(list,j,i)
        findPermutations (list,i+1)
        swap(list,j,i) #clean up - return to previous condition.
```

Where `swap(list,i,j)` swaps between the element at index `i` and the element at index `j` (easy to implement).

Now, your foo(list) can be anything. If for example you have a list [a b c] and you want to calculate `(a/b)/c` (the example in comments), it can be done as follows:

```
foo(list):
  if list.size() == 0: //sanity check for empty lists
       return 0
  res = list[0]
  for each i from 1 to list.length:
      res = res / list[i]
  return res
```

---

It is easy to see that indeed n! different permutations are created with the findPermutations pseudo code, because each level is recursing `i` times, and `i` is monotonically decreasing by 1.

Comment: If I don't need to print every list, but to make some further calculations on it ? For example, in the first list, If I wanted to do 2 divided by 4 divided by 6, how could I do ?

Comment: Then I don't understand the question. Instead of `print list` you can do whatever you want.

Comment: For example, once I have my new list, I would like to divide each element by the next one, would it be possible ?

Comment: @user3307705 I am not following. Can you provide a detailed example? From the example in your question - it seems like you are asking for finding all permutations.

Comment: I need to get all the possible permutations. Then, for each permuted list (in the example, they are 6 of them), I would like to make further calculations. In the example, on the third list [6,2,4], I would like to do 6 divided by 2 (=3), then divided by 4 (=0.75).

Comment: @user3307705 Here you go. See edit. just invoke any function you want. I even included the function doing what you described here.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know how to set this part in the recursion way.